# Faulty PNP Transistor switch fix...what is causing the noise on the base?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, noise, pnp, ham-radio

I built a ham radio amplifier kit that takes about 5 watts drive and makes 70 watts.  It is called a MiniPA70.

Here is a website someone put together describing its build/use.

http://pa-11019.blogspot.com/2016/11/diy-kits-70w-ssb-linear-hf-power.html

I have been having problems with it and am trying to understand its flaws... there are a few.

Take a look at the switch shown below.  The idea is that when the PTT jumper is grounded, the PNP transistor switch's on and delivers power.  Sometimes this works and sometimes this does not.  I am trying to fix its issues....

Using an oscilloscope, I have looked at the noise present as Peak to Peak variations at various points around the transistor.  I note that either with the PTT switched activated or the PTT switch deactivated, the noise on the Emitter is negligible.  The noise on the base is not.

When the PTT switch is activated (grounded), the noise on the base is minimal.  When the PTT switch is left floating (deactivated), there is substantial noise on the base.  Much more than on the emitter.  It is this noise, that switches on the transistor erroneously.  Why are there different amounts of noise on the emitter and base and why is it a function of of weather the base has a path to ground?

I also looked at the noise on the ground point and it is also minimal.

I am wondering if the transistors I have been using are flawed or the resistors are bad?  What process cause there to be more noise post resistor than pre resistor when the resistor is floating in space and that noise to disappear when it is grounded/forms a divider.

Thanks for any insight. I have to redesign this to make it work properly, but that said, there are a number of kits floating around with this faulty design.

[image: pnp switch]

Comment: What noise to you measure if you put a 20K resistor in series with the emitter? What kind of noise? Mains frequency ripple? Switching regulator frequency noise (like from your 13.8V source)? Do you have anything earthed in the circuit?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I used a high quality linear power supply as well as a dc battery, I see about the same noise, little less with the battery.  When I say noise, I mean to same "More than 85 millivolts peak to peak variation".  If I leave the ptt switch off and measure before R1, I see 85 millivolts of variation.  If I measure at the intersection of R1 and R2, I see well more than 100 millivolts of variation. It is enough to activate the transistor.    Why the difference before R1 and at the intersection of r1 and r2

Comment: @Atomique Actually, the pnp, when it lets out is 130 ma, activates a relay which switches on the amplifier.  That stage will let out the 70 watts.  The problem I am having was ... when the amplifier was not activated by grounding the base/ptt, the rely was intermittently activating.  The problem I see with the relay intermittently activating is related to the noise present on the base when not activating.  It is not a well designed circuit.

Comment: 100mV really is not enough to activate any silicon transistor.  You'd need 600mV as a minimum.  Is R1 open?  It may be.  Also, are you picking up room noise?  When the transistor is off, the base draws essentially zero current and thus presents as open circuit, so you are just connecting your o'scope probe to a node on the circuit isolated by 10k to everything, so stray room noise could be picked up by the traces/wiring you're connecting to.

Comment: @Atomique  The noise looks to be well above 2 volts. I know I said 100mv before, but that was because I was only looking at the noise free versions.  When R2 is connected to ground, the noise almost disappears.... the noise on the base is very small sometimes <85 mv,  sometimes less than 30mv. It is when R2 is ungrounded that I see lots more noise on the oscilloscope--sometimes triggering the pnp.

Comment: @Atomique On a breadboard, this PNP configuration appears to work better than when on the amplifier.  I did look at that.  I did not see any random pnp activations on the breadboard.  I put the same transistor back in the amp and saw the problem, thats when I looked  into noise as the issue.   I am wondering if it is just a bad design to leave a wire floating like that and then ground to activate?

Comment: The open base circuit seems to catch some HF noise and this is rectified by the base emitter junction. A simple capacitor of 100 nF - 1 uF parallel to R1 should be able to suppress this. The input of the 7805 should also be filtered with a similar capacitor to GND to prevent oscillation.